# Problema con Host Virtual de Wamp y archivo .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wamp, virtualhost

Cree un host virtual desde **Wampserver** pero tengo un pequeño problema respecto al archivo `.htaccess`, si dicho archivo esta dentro de mi proyecto, **Wampserver** me arroja un error:

> Internal Server Error

Pero si quito el archivo `.htaccess` funciona correctamente el Host Virtual, no entiendo que estaria pasando.

En el archivo `.htaccess` tengo lo siguiente:

```
#impedir que vea el listado del directorio

Options All -Indexes

#URLS Amigables
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución en el siguiente enlace: [How can i set htaccess file for virtual host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316754/how-can-i-set-htaccess-file-for-virtual-host)

Primero habilité `vhost` en el archivo `httpd.conf`.

- **vHost**:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.ws
        DocumentRoot /home/me/Projects/website/build
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /home/me/Projects/website/build>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

- Luego, en el archivo **.htaccess**

```
###START MOD_REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #REMOVE .html EXTENSION
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
###END MOD_REWRITE
```